# Using Php mysql query do not get data from php class, though there are data

Tags: php, mysql

```
class book {

function __construct() {
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('can nit connect to DB');
mysql_select_db('atomic_project', $conn) or die('can not connect to db');
}

public function listView() {
    $allData = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `book`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
        $allData [] = $row;
    }
    return $allData;
}
```

}

My index page

```
    $listViewObj = new book();
    $allData = $listViewObj->listView();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($allData);
    echo "<pre>";
```

Here is my code and the table [here is my table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KoKm.png)  , i can insert data into table but no row is found
i can't understand why no data is shown, please help me

[image]

Comment: Where is your class object and where is you calling this function. Please share your full code?

Comment: $book_show=new book(); and then $book_show->listView(); use this after your code.

Comment: what error r u getting??

Comment: what is your database password???

Comment: and y r u asking for db password, OP using localhost. @WisdmLabs

Comment: Because the syntax mysqli_ connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); want database password.

Comment: i call from index page $listViewObj = new book();
    $allData = $listViewObj->listView();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($allData);
    echo "<pre>";

Comment: i have no password

Comment: there is no error shown not in browser or phpstorm and netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
class book {

public function listView() {
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('can nit connect to DB');
    mysql_select_db('atomic_project', $conn) or die('can not connect to db');

    $allData = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `book`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($row);
        $allData [] = $row;
    }
   return $allData;
}
}
book::listView(); //scope resolution operator 
?>
```

### or calling function by object

```
$obj = new book();
$obj->listView();
```